# Whitespace in pyplot legend entry?

Tags: python, matplotlib, whitespace, legend

I want to add some spacing between the end of the legend entry and the legend border. I've tried using the arguments for `pyplot.legend` but I haven't found a combination that works. Here's a minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.0,1.0,10)
y = x

fig = plt.figure()
p, = plt.plot(x,y,'-o')
plt.legend([p],['$y = x$'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

I've tried

```
plt.legend([p],['$y = x\/$'], loc='best')
plt.legend([p],['$y = x{ }$'], loc='best')
plt.legend([p],['$y = x\:$'], loc='best')
plt.legend([p],['$y = x$ '], loc='best')
```

But none of them work. It seems `pyplot` is too smart and removes any trailing whitespace. Is there any way to accomplish this?

To give you an example of why I want this, it's to balance out space on both sides with using one marker instead of two in the legend, see example below. The space beside the **W-Y** and **Exp.** is much smaller than the space on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want with a combination of the `kwargs` `borderpad` and `handletextpad`.

[(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend)

Comment: That could work; however, `borderpad` adds padding all the way around. Which then requires the use of `handletextheight` and `labelspacing`, on top of `handletextpad`. I was really hoping there would just be an easy fix to add a whitespace character at the end of an entry.

Comment: @William The legend code in rather complex with lots of nooks and carnies, there could very will be a parameter to tune _exactly_ what you want that I do not know about. It might be worth some time digging around in the code.  What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: @William There is the snarky solution of turning the legend frame off so you can't tell ;)  I would specifically look at how the bounding box is generated, I think that the point artists is much wider than it looks which is what gives you that extra padding.

Comment: I managed to get it to work (through brute-force trial-and-error). I just used the legend `kwargs` in the end. Interestingly enough, if you don't change `numpoints = 1`, you can just add space to the end, such as `plt.legend([p],['$y = x$   '])`, and it works. If you reduce `numpoints` to 1, then the space no longer works.